# Symfony2 composer adding own bundle requirement

Tags: symfony-2.1, composer-php

How can I install a specific Bundle (for example SonataGoutteBundle) to my Symfony2 project **via composer**?

I tried this, but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "sonata-project/sonatagouttebundle",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataGoutteBundle.git",
                "type": "git"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
     "php": ">=5.3.3",
     [...],
     "sonata-project/sonatagouttebundle": "dev-master"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataGoutteBundle.git"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "vendor/bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The SonataGoutteBundle **must** have a composer.json

In this particular case, this would work:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "sonata-project/goutte",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataGoutteBundle.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
     "php": ">=5.3.3",
     "sonata-project/goutte": "dev-master"
}
```

For all options see the [documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories)

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a link to an archive (like zip) in "dist" section. If you want to use git you should define "source" section instead:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "sonata-project/sonatagouttebundle",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataGoutteBundle.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "sonata-project/sonatagouttebundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

More about defining custom repositories: http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories